# Apache Spark: Read umlauts with SparkContext.textFile

Tags: encoding, apache-spark

I wrote a Spark Application which reads, filters and prints data from a CSV file, saved in HDFS. When I download the CSV to my pc and open it, everything is ok, all umlauts are displayed correctly. BUT: When I run my application, the umlauts are not shown correctly, they all are displayed as `ï¿½`.

Is there a possibility to set an encoding for loading the csv via .textFile transaction in Spark or to "convert" the input?

**This seems to be a Won't Fix:** https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-1849

The problem occurs due to the UTF-8 encoding of the file. Seems, that there's a workaround by using `.hadoopFile`, but I don't know how to use this method. Can someone help?

**Tried the following code, without success:**

test.txt file:

```
ÄPPLE
APPLE
ÖPPLE
ÜPPLE
```

Spark program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    String inputFile = args[0];

    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("EdekaOwgCheckUmlauts");
    sparkConf.registerKryoClasses(new Class<?>[]{
        Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable"),
        Class.forName("org.apache.hadoop.io.Text")
    });

    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf);

    JavaRDD<Text> input = sc.hadoopFile(inputFile, TextInputFormat.class, LongWritable.class, Text.class).map(new Function<Tuple2<LongWritable,Text>, Text>() {
        @Override
        public Text call(Tuple2<LongWritable, Text> v1) throws Exception {
            return v1._2();
        }
    });

    JavaRDD<Text> filtered = input.filter(new Function<Text, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(Text v1) throws Exception {
            return v1.toString().toLowerCase().contains("pple");        // LOOK FOR ÄPPLE, APPLE etc.
        }
    });

    List<Text> collected = filtered.collect();
    System.out.println("=== PRINT ===");
    for(Text row : collected) {
        try {
            System.out.println(row.decode(row.getBytes()));
        } catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Console Output:

```
ï¿½PPLE
APPLE
ï¿½PPLE
ï¿½PPLE
```

**The file is encoded with the charset iso-8859-1**

Calling `file -i myfile.csv` shows the following information:

```
myfile.csv: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
```

I tried to convert this charset into utf-8 using this code:

```
JavaRDD<String> inputRDD = sc.textFile(inputFile);
List<String> asList = inputRDD.collect();
for(String a : asList) {

    try {
        byte[] isoBytes = a.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
        System.out.println(new String(isoBytes, "UTF-8"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

without success, the console prints `?` instead ä, ö, ü...

Comment: Did you look at [this example](https://github.com/databricks/learning-spark/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/oreilly/learningsparkexamples/scala/LoadJsonWithElephantBird.scala)?

Comment: Thank you for the link! But how can I use this with Java API? Don't know how to "fill" the .newAPIHaoopFile method...

Comment: It looks like the problem with your data is that it is not UTF-8 encoded. So the first thing you should learn is the actual encoding  (cp1252?).

Comment: Due to "file -i myfile.csv" command, the encoding seems to be iso-8859-1

Answer (score 2):

Here a shortest version that use hadoopFile and string recoding from right charset (iso-8859-1 to UTF-8):

```
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
import org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat

val file=sc.hadoopFile[LongWritable, Text, TextInputFormat]("/file...").
 mapPartitions(
   _.map(line => new String(line._2.getBytes, 0, line._2.getLength, "iso-8859-1"))
)
```

Hope that help.

This only work with hadoop.io.Text not with string after reading file with spark textFile.

Someone perhaps have understanding of why ?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own custom TextInputFormat and use it with newAPIHadoopFile.
TextInputFormat uses Text.class to handle the data, which stores data in UTF-8 : the main idea is to use String.class instead (with the right encoding).

Follow the TextInputFormat class and re-write what you need to change. This would include re-writing your own RecordReader, LineRecordReader, SplitLineReader. This should not be too complicated, but unfortunately quite long.

You should then be able to use your custom text input format like this :

```
// JavaSparkContext sc
//File path path
JavaPairRDD<String, BytesWritable> zip = sc.newAPIHadoopFile(path, 
         CustomTextInputFormat.class,
         LongWritable.class,
         String.class,
         sc.hadoopConfiguration());
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This could be the solution of my problem, thank you! Can someone help me how to create these custom classes?

Comment: I did the same thing for an output format and it worked fine. The input format looks a little trickier. I don't have any code to show you for your case, but if you give it a go I'll try to help if needed